# How to use Animated refs in transform space-separated string function values react-native

Tags: react-native, transform, react-native-web

I've encountered a deprecation warning regarding the use of the "transform" style array value in React Native. Instead, I'm advised to use space-separated string functions for transformations, like `scaleX(2) rotateX(15deg)`.

`"transform" style array value is deprecated. Use space-separated string functions, e.g., "scaleX(2) rotateX(15deg)"`

In my code, I have a ref `useRef(new Animated.Value(isActive ? 10 : 0))` that I intend to use within the transform style. Initially, I used it like `transform: [{scale: ref}]`.

However, with the deprecation, I'm unsure how to incorporate the ref within space-separated string functions. Could you guide me on how to rewrite this using the string function approach, like `transform: 'scale(ref)'`?